# PLSQL: Convert CLOB to XML

Tags: xml, plsql

I have the following select:

```
select XMLTYPE.createXML(contents) from log_sync_calls_xmls where id=2;
```

This gives me the following error:

[image]

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

createXML api accepts String/CLOB and returns XMLTYPE value.
Better use this in insert where you want to convert a CLOB data to store into xMLTYPE column.

In a SELECT statement, the outcome of the query will always be displayed in text format.
So, some older versions of Toad or PLSQL developer will have this error.
Please try this using Oracle SQLDeveloper.